# Display different data in different time range in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table to show the user the transaction record. But the data I wanted to show is from today 6 pm until tomorrow's 2 am. I have tried using current_date to select the data. However, I realize once the time passed 12 am, the data from 6 pm until 12 am is gone, only left with the data from 12 am until 2 am. so I have created an if-else method to only show the data from current date 6pm-11: 59 am and another one to show current date 6 pm until 2 am, but it seems doesn't work. may I know what is the problem?

```
<?php
                            include_once '../tmkdashboard/includes/db.php';
                                $admin_session = $_SESSION['u_admin'];
                                $currenttime = new DateTime('2014-09-08 06:00:00');
                                $hour = $deliverytime->format('H');

                                $get_member = "SELECT * 
                                               FROM transaction_record_tpg
                                               WHERE ";

                                if($hour >= 0 && $hour <= 2 ){

                                        $get_member.= "collect_outlet = '$admin_session'

                                              AND collected_datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
                                              AND collected_datetime <= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 HOUR";

                                    } elseif($hour >= 18 && $hour <= 23 ) {

                                        $get_member.= "collect_outlet = '$admin_session' 
                                               AND collected_datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 HOUR
                                               AND collected_datetime <= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 17 HOUR";
                            };             
                                $get_member.= ";";

                                $run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);

                                $i = 0;



                                while($row_orders = mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer)){

                                $id = $row_orders['trans_id'];

                                $user = $row_orders['user_id'];

                                $debit = $row_orders['m_debit'];

                                $credit = $row_orders['m_credit'];

                                $date = $row_orders['collected_datetime'];

                                $i++;


                            ?>
                        <tr><!-- tr Starts -->

                            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $user; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $debit; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>


                        </tr><!-- tr Ends -->
                            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull transactions for 6PM today until 2AM tomorrow try the select query below:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM transaction_record_tpg
WHERE collect_outlet = '$admin_session'
  AND collected_datetime >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 18:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
  AND collected_datetime <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 02:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Example SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14f479/1

Comment: Hi Genome, your query is correct but what i wanted to achieve is:
let say today is 26th, i wanted to show the data from 6pm until 27th 2am. but the problem is when the current time is 27th 12am or later, the record of 26th from 6pm until 1159pm is not showing. i wanted the query to show the record from 26th 6pm until 1159pm on 27th 12am or later as well. Then, at 27th 6pm or later, it shows the data that record from 27th 6pm until 28th 2am.

Comment: @laowai0609 Genome has demonstrated how best to address problems in sql. If you're still struggling, take a leaf out of their book, and amend your question accordingly.